# Export varbinary to file (image) from multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a MSSQL 2k8 database, in it I have a table of format below.

```
Employee Number   |   Segment   |   Data (varbinary(8000))
----------------------------------------------------------
111111            |     1       |    0x01234567...DEF
111111            |     2       |    0x01234567...DEF
111111            |     3       |    0x01234567...DEF
```

The data (varbinary) column makes up a picture but unfortunately is split in multiple segments by a process I cannot control.

Is there a way to export this data via an SQL script/procedure to a file? I have seem some questions that answer for a varbinary(max) column but I can't for the life of me work out how to stitch these all together into one file.

Note: Some of the files have >500 segments but this procedure will not be occuring exceedingly regularly.

Answer (score 0):

If the picture can be reconstructed by simply concatenating all of the segments, then you could try [execsql.py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/execsql), which is a SQL script processor written in Python (by me).  It has a metacommand of this form:

```
EXPORT <table_or_view> TO <filename> AS RAW
```

which will concatenate all columns and rows in the given table or view.

Comment: Thanks rd_nielsen,

I ended up having to complete this in an external process, using powershell due to ease of use in a Windows environment.